# SASS mixin with dynamic argument list does not work with only one argument

Tags: css, sass, webpack, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

I wrote the following mixin to dynamicly create two classes used for a title and subtitle. I wanted to be able to add arrays of arguments to the classes. But I only got it working if I have multiple values in the arrays, not with only one. I suspect its not treated as an array.

```
@mixin argument ($key, $value) {
    #{$key}: $value;
}

// dynamic mixin that creates two seperate classes for a header title and subtitle
@mixin header-titles($name, $title-size, $title-color, $sub-size, $sub-color, $title-extra: false, $sub-extra: false) {

    .#{$name}-title {
        @include font($bold-font, 900, $title-size, $title-color)
        @if $title-extra {
            @each $t-extra in $title-extra{
                @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));
            }
        }
    }

    .#{$name}-subtitle {
        @include font($bold-font, 900, $sub-size, $sub-color)
        @if $sub-extra {
            @each $s-extra in $sub-extra {
                @include argument(nth($s-extra,1),nth($s-extra,2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works if you call it like this in SASS and run `mix.sass('homepage.scss');` for it using gulp watch and laravel elixir.

```
@include header-titles(
    'fubar',
    $fubar-title-font-size,
    $fubar-title-text-color,
    $fubar-sub-title-font-size,
    $fubar-sub-title-text-color,
    ((margin, 50px 0 0 0),(padding, 50px 0 0 0)),((margin, 50px 0 0 0),(padding, 50px 0 0 0))
)
```

But not if called like this

```
@include header-titles(
    'fubar',
    $fubar-title-font-size,
    $fubar-title-text-color,
    $fubar-sub-title-font-size,
    $fubar-sub-title-text-color,
    ((margin, 50px 0 0 0)),((margin, 50px 0 0 0))
)
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Error: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`
        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss
>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));
   ------------------------------------------^

    at options.error ({obfuscated projectdirname}\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:286:26)
  status: 1,
  file: '{obfuscated projectdirname}/resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss',
  line: 86,
  column: 51,
  message: 'resources\\assets\\sass\\_mixins.scss\nError: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`\n        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss\n>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));\n   ------------------------------------------^\n',
  formatted: 'Error: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`\n        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss\n>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));\n   ------------------------------------------^\n',
  messageFormatted: 'resources\\assets\\sass\\_mixins.scss\nError: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`\n        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss\n>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));\n   ------------------------------------------^\n',
  messageOriginal: 'index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`',
  relativePath: 'resources\\assets\\sass\\_mixins.scss',
  name: 'Error',
  stack: 'Error: resources\\assets\\sass\\_mixins.scss\nError: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`\n        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss\n>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));\n   ------------------------------------------^\n\n    at options.error ({obfuscated projectdirname}\\exroot\\node_modules\\node-sass\\lib\\index.js:286:26)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-sass' }
{ Error: resources\assets\sass\_mixins.scss
Error: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`
        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss
>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));
   ------------------------------------------^

    at options.error ({obfuscated projectdirname}\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:286:26)
  status: 1,
  file: '{obfuscated projectdirname}/resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss',
  line: 86,
  column: 51,
  message: 'resources\\assets\\sass\\_mixins.scss\nError: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`\n        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss\n>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));\n   ------------------------------------------^\n',
  formatted: 'Error: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`\n        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss\n>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));\n   ------------------------------------------^\n',
  messageFormatted: 'resources\\assets\\sass\\_mixins.scss\nError: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`\n        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss\n>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));\n   ------------------------------------------^\n',
  messageOriginal: 'index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`',
  relativePath: 'resources\\assets\\sass\\_mixins.scss',
  name: 'Error',
  stack: 'Error: resources\\assets\\sass\\_mixins.scss\nError: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`\n        on line 86 of resources/assets/sass/_mixins.scss\n>>         @include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));\n   ------------------------------------------^\n\n    at options.error ({obfuscated projectdirname}\\node_modules\\node-sass\\lib\\index.js:286:26)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-sass' }
```

My google-fu abandoned me when trying to find out what this error means.

My question: what did I do wrong here? Is there maybe a better way to do this?

Sorry for the long code blocks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a ***known problem/behavior with respect to single element lists***. As mentioned in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1702) you can add an extra comma at the end to make Sass treat it as a list. This method works from Sass v3.3.0 onwards. (*Tested at [sassmeister.com](http://www.sassmeister.com/) with v3.4.21.*)

```
@include header-titles(
    'fubar',
    $fubar-title-font-size,
    $fubar-title-text-color,
    $fubar-sub-title-font-size,
    $fubar-sub-title-text-color,
    ((margin, 50px 0 0 0),),((margin, 50px 0 0 0),)
)
```

When it is sent without that extra comma, it seems like the Sass compiler treats it as `$title-extra` is a list with two values where the first one is `margin` and the second one is `50px 0 0 0`.  The behavior is similar for the `$sub-extra` list also. This is what happens at sassmeister.com when I tried to output the individual values within the `@each` loop. Since the 1<sup>st</sup> value of `$title-extra` itself is just `margin`, the compiler is failing at the below line (within first iteration of `@each` loop) because there is no second value to pick using the `nth`.

```css
/* $t-extra in 1st iteration is only margin and so nth($t-extra,2) reports error */
@include argument(nth($t-extra,1),nth($t-extra,2));
```

Comment: This 'hack' works! But its very weird and counterintuitive behavior imho.Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I agree @Sitethief but seems like there is no alternate other than the hack :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134788/discussion-between-sitethief-and-harry).

Comment: I had similar issue where I had a mixin (declared on a global mixin file) and on a different file I was trying to pass in a map of extra CSS prop/values. I found that the following worked;

```
@if(length($additional) > 0) {
    @each $pair in $additional {
        $prop: nth($pair, 1);
        // @NOTE: Even though the length of this pair is 2
        //        if I hard code `2` as the `nth()` key below
        //        it breaks...
        $value: nth($pair, length($pair));
        #{$prop}: #{$value};
    }
}
```

No idea why but it works!